# bazaar 2.4 external merge tool

Tags: bazaar

i installed the latest stable bzr version and gladly discover the external merge feature.
but i cant get it to work

i'm using bcompare as my tool , and no matter what i do , when i try to resolve conflicts i choose bcompare and it always state "External merge tool bcompare is not available"

i tried with and without putting the bcomapre directory in PATH with no luck.
i also tried it outside of gui and directly in bazaar conf with the following lines:

[MERGE]

bzr.mergetool.bcompare = bcompare.exe {this} {other} {base} {result}

bzr.default_mergetool = bcompare

please help me
Gil Idelson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message "External merge tool bcompare is not available" means that it is not able to find the executable either directly or on the PATH. You can try putting the full path to bcompare.exe in the merge tool definition. If there are spaces in the path, enclose it in quotes. If you do so, please be aware that there is a [known bug](http://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/828803) in qconfig when editing merge tool definitions that include quotes.

If you are adding the BCompare directory to your PATH, make sure that you restart the command window that you are invoking qconflicts from, to pick up the change to the system PATH.

If you are still having trouble, please [file a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bzr/+filebug) with the Bazaar project.

Comment: thanks dOxxx. i reinstall bcompare in a directory without spaces in the name and now its working.